# How to make the marshmallow swirl for Chocolate Marshmallow Ice cream from scratch?

Tags: ice-cream, marshmallow

My wife loves chocolate marshmallow swirl ice cream, but she doesn't like store-bought marshmallows. I would like to surprise her with homemade chocolate marshmallow swirl ice cream, but I am unsure how to make the marshmallow swirl.

Here are some of the options I have considered:

1. make homemade marshmallow creme (eg Fluff)
2. melt homemade marshmallows

both of these seem experimental.

Does anyone have a tried and true technique?

Comment: Thanks for changing  recipe to technique. That's what I was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made marshmallows using [Alton Brown's method](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/homemade-marshmallows-recipe.html); it works and is a lot of fun. If you don't form the individual marshmallows, but just swirl it into the ice cream while it's still a sticky mess, that should work for your swirl.

There is even a video in that link.

As ElendilTheTall mentioned in comments, you probably should reduce the amount of gelatin in Alton's recipe, perhaps by a third, to get a good swirl.

Comment: I would say reducing the amount of gelatin in a standard recipe would give softer, more swirlable results.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I'll buy that.

Comment: Made this tonite with 3 packets at 13 minutes on high. came out very well. Put into a pastry bag with a wide tip and mixed with the ice cream that came out of the machine into a glass container, and it's now in the freezer.  the rest went into a baking pan, just like Alton's video.

Comment: @rbp Great! Glad we could help.